# TypeError: Date is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, date, constructor, typeerror, acrobat

So, I've been making forms for my company for some time now with pretty easy Javascript that has worked for me in the past. However all of a sudden it's kicking out the error: `TypeError: Date is not a constructor`

The Code:

```
var Date = this.getField("Text1");
Date.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy",new Date());
```

It works on all my old forms, but now it won't work on new ones... and I've tried making a new button on an old form - just copying and pasting the code, and then it'll break all the other buttons and spit out the same error.

Running: Windows 7 64-bit with Acrobat XI 11.0.10

Answer (score 25):

The variable `Date` is hiding the global function [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and causing this error. Because of how scoping works in JS, the inner-most use of a name is the one that matters.

In this case, you declare `var Date` which becomes the only `Date` the function knows about. When you assign it a field or text (`Date = this.getField...`), you hide the global class.

You can rename your variable (I would suggest `date`, as capital names are typically reserved for types) or explicitly reference `new window.Date` when you go to construct a new date.

Comment: Had the same issue using AngularJs. There was a service that was being injected called 'Date'. Renaming the service (if possible) or using window.Date solves the issue.

Comment: For anyone coming here searching in relation to React or similar; there was a JSX-element named `Date` to add such a strange behaviour of not finding Date in the execution environment which was web too; The answer hinted to look for in that direction.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
  var d = new window.Date();
```

Comment: I was using `var x = new Date(someNumber)` in React and it wasn't working. This approach solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Might be this answer will be helpful in future. I was using below code

```
var dateTime=new date();
```

But right code is

```
var dateTime=new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a variable called "Date" because there's a built-in object in JS called that (you're using it in your code, actually). Change the name to something else.

**var Date= somthing;**  <-- wrong declare, you should not use build -in object name

Comment: There is no problem with defining the variable named Date. The problem is that it is a global variable that might be used by many other things on a page. Check @ssube answer for details

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and I solved it! don't use **"Date"** as variable because this causes conflict with Global function **Date();**

Exemple: Wrong !

```
var Date = new Date();
     document.getElementById('dateCopy').innerHTML = Date.getFullYear();
```

Right:

```
var DateTime = new Date();
      document.getElementById('dateCopy').innerHTML = DateTime.getFullYear();
```

In your case:

```
var DateTime = this.getField("Text1");
DateTime.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy",new Date());
```