# How to set date in JQuery Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am working on Asp.Net. I have a JQuery datepicker.

html:

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control Date" id="DtAccountable" value="" />
```

JQuery:

```
  $(".Date").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    });
```

Everything works fine, until when I click edit button the date from database is loaded.

```
  $('.Date').val(Date);
```

But the selected date will still be todays date or previous selected date.

So I searched and found some answers and tried.

```
$('.Date').datepicker("setDate", new Date(Date) );
```

But I get error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Date is not a constructor ...

How do I do this?

Comment: What is the `Date` returned from Controller (Server side), i.e. is it an object or a string?

Comment: My advice, return Date from server as a string in the following format: `'12/31/2000'`. Then use without `new Date` as follows: `$('.Date').datepicker("setDate", Date );`

Answer (score 0):

As this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30130303/6448640) suggests :

You get the error because you already using a variable named `Date`,

Try changing the variable to another name.

As:

```
$('.Date').val(myDate);

$('.Date').datepicker("setDate", new Date(myDate) );
```